# How to count the number of files in a directory AND its sub directories

Tags: c#

I am creating a program to count the number of files in a directory and display the total when needed. So far it can count the total number of files in the directory but i would like to know how to edit my current code so it also counts the files within sub directories.

This is just a basic c# application. I am sure there is an easy way to do this but i am a beginner and cant seem to find the code i need to do so.

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("sourcePath");
        int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

The expected results of the code come out well and show the total number of files in the directory. I just need to edit it so it includes sub directories and their files

Comment: Have a look at MSDN for  [`System.IO.Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.7.2) and you will find all kinds of useful functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to EnumerateFiles with all subdirectories with C# DirectoryInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253936/how-to-enumeratefiles-with-all-subdirectories-with-c-sharp-directoryinfo)

Answer (score 9):

For a directory count use

```
var countDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

For a file count use

```
var countFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

Then you can add them together, if needed.

Comment: The 2 lines are inversed here. 1st code snippet is for directory count, and 2nd is file count.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is to perform a single `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` for both directory and file Count as browsing the file system is expensive.

```
var fileAndDirectoriesCount = new DirectoryInfo(@"sourcePath")
        .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Count();
```

If you want to get it separately :

```
var res = new DirectoryInfo(@"sourcePath")
        .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .GroupBy(s => s is DirectoryInfo)
        .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Count());

var directoryCount = res.ContainsKey(true) ? res[true] : 0;
var fileCount = res.ContainsKey(false) ? res[false] : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int fileCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
int subDirCount = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
int total = fileCount + subDirCount;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used this method and its the best one i have found. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Joe no problem! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate: [Counting the number of files in a folder in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193126/counting-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-in-c-sharp)

Solution: `int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;`